# Problem books in different languages

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I simply love problem books in mathematics, though you have to know how to use them properly. I think they are useful to me because most of time I study on my own. I'm thinking here at MSE, since we have a lot of non-native English speakers including myself, if you know some problem books in your mother tongue that haven't been published yet in English, you can post their titles here.

(To see problem books in English see this question: [Problem books in higher mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185607/problem-books-in-higher-mathematics)).

The book can be written in any language. I know so many foreign ones, but if I don't know the language of your book, I think it can be useful for another student who knows the language of your book.

I think this question is interesting also because we can see a little bit the mathematical books outside, beyond our English horizons.

To be more precise, undergraduate mathematics books are preferable, such as algebraic topology, analysis, undergraduate algebra, etc...

I will start:

**French books**

Algebra

[Toute l'algèbre de la licence-Jean. Pierre Escofier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2100489763)

[Théorie de Galois : Cours et exercices corrigés. Jean-Pierre Escofier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/210007685X)

[Toute l'algèbre du 1er cycle : Cours et exercices corrigés. Jean-Pierre Escofier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2100063413)

[Exercices d'algèbre. Aviva Szpirglas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2842251288)

Analysis

[Mathématiques pour le DEUG, tome 2, Analyse 1re année : Cours et exercices avec solutions. François Liret, Dominique Martinais](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2100031511)

[Mathématiques L3 - Analyse: Cours complet avec 600 tests et exercices corrigés](http://www.amazon.fr/Math%C3%A9matiques-L3-Analyse-exercices-corrig%C3%A9s/dp/2744073504/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1355998014&sr=8-3)

**German books**

Analysis

[Übungsbuch zur Analysis 1: Aufgaben und Lösungen. Otto Forster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3658003359)

[Übungsbuch zur Analysis 2: Aufgaben und Lösungen. Otto Forster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3658005122)

**Portuguese books**

Complex analysis

[Uma introdução à variável complexa, 476 exercícios resolvidos. Salahoddin Shokranian](http://www.livrariacultura.com.br/scripts/resenha/resenha.asp?nitem=5110158&sid=718134159141220282597748060)

Answer (score 1):

I would definetely recommend you [100 Problems in Elementary Mathematics](http://books.google.ca/books?isbn=048623875X) by [Hugo Steinhaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Steinhaus). Although it was published in many languages (English too), I was told that some versions are different than the original (from what I've heard at least German and Russian versions are the same as Polish print).