# Good problem books at a relatively advanced level?

Tags: reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I have been searching for problem books on advanced topics.

By advanced I am referring to the undergraduate level and above. I am looking for something analogous to the olympiad type problem books found at the high school level. I am hoping to supplement my learning with challenging problems in these topics and 
I have so far found a few, namely:

- Putnam and Beyond by Razvan Gelca
- Problem-Solving Through Problems by Loren C. Larson
- Linear Algebra Problem Book by Halmos.

But with the exception of Halmos, these books do not cover the topics I am interested in deeply enough, these include:

- Abstract Algebra
- Real Analysis
- Differential Equations

and a few other topics.

Just to reiterate, I am looking for books that entirely consist of difficult problems. Thanks.

Comment: [Halmos' book on Hilbert spaces](http://www.amazon.com/Hilbert-Space-Problem-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387906851) is pretty grueling.

Comment: Definitely the sort of the thing I am looking for, but alas it is seems to be quite a bit beyond my level right now. Perhaps I may end up using it one day though. Thanks.

Comment: See [IMO Math](http://www.imomath.com) and [Putnam Archive](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive).

Comment: Maybe it would be better to post (or even better to search for) a separate question for abstract algebra, real analysis, ODEs.

Comment: Abstract algebra: [Good problem book on Abstract Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174596/good-problem-book-on-abstract-algebra) and maybe some of the questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/174596).

Comment: These questions are about calculus/analysis, but the answers include books about real analysis. (It is probably worth adding that various people will [understand *real analysis* a bit differently](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3310).)
[Book recommendation for analysis problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009371/book-recommendation-for-analysis-problems),
[Suggest books in calculus to improve problem solving skills](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170196/suggest-books-in-calculus-to-improve-problem-solving-skills)

Comment: And here is a post somewhat similar to yours - i.e., not directed towards one specific area: [Problem books in higher mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185607/problem-books-in-higher-mathematics).